# Trying to install TAFFO leads to a CMake error: re2::re2 not available

Tags: cmake, re2

I am trying to install TAFFO by following the Readme https://github.com/TAFFO-org/TAFFO.
I am running the program in VM VirtualBox in Linux Ubuntu and with LLVM 14.
Everything works until I try to run `cmake .. -DTAFFO_BUILD_ORTOOLS=ON` which leads to the error:

```
CMake Error at build/_deps/or-tools-src/cmake/deps.cmake:69 (message): Target re2::re2 not available. Call Stack (most recent call first): build/_deps/or-tools-src/CMakeLists.txt:304 (include)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "/home/jeffrey/TAFFO/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". See also "/home/jeffrey/TAFFO/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I have tried manually building re2, specifying the location to the re2 file and doing `dpkg -L libre2-dev`but none of it has worked and I'm not sure what else to do. I imagine it is from doing something wrong earlier, but I can't say for sure where my issues come from. Earlier, I had some other errors when running the command, but they were fixed by installing something else.

Comment: Do you have `pkg-config` installed and do you have a file called `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/re2.pc`?